# How to show for each created draggable PictureBox the position (x,y) in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, timer, draggable, windows-forms-designer

I have made a picture box called "pb_test" that contains a picture of a factory, when I click it, it creates a new picture box after each click in a specific location of my windows form.

Each created picture box is draggable, that means that I can move it anywhere on my form.

I've created a label on my form that shows the position (x,y) of my draggable picture box. When I create a picture box and drag it, the label shows its position (x,y) , but if I create another one, the new one when I drag it, the label shows (x,y) , but if I drag the first one created, the label doesn't change, and still showing data (x,y) of the last created one.

This is my code:

```
List<PictureBox> list_pboxes = new List<PictureBox>();

        private void pb_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pbox = new PictureBox();
            pbox.Name = "factory";
            pbox.Location = new Point(600, 600);
            pbox.Size = new Size(100, 70);
            pbox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
            pbox.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            pbox.Image = pb_test.Image;
            pbox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pbox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            this.Controls.Add(pbox);
            list_pboxes.Add(pbox);
            ControlExtension.Draggable(pbox, true);   
        }

        private void timer_ListpicBoxes_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (PictureBox p in list_pboxes)
            {
                lbl_mouse.Text = p.Location.X.ToString() + " , " + p.Location.Y.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need a variable that indicates which `PictureBox` the `Timer` is supposed to be getting the `Location` of. That might be of type `PictureBox` and refer to the `PictureBox` itself or it might be type `int` and contain the index in the `List` you already have. When you click a `PictureBox` to drag it, update that variable and then use that variable in your `Tick` event handler.

Comment: Could you please put your answer as a code?

Comment: No, because I'm not here to write your code you. I've pointed you in the direction you need to go, but it's up to you to go there. I'll write code if someone has already made an honest attempt but has encountered a specific issue along the way. You haven't actually made an attempt yet, so it's not even really appropriate that you posted here at all. "I want to do this, show me how" questions are not appropriate for SO.

Comment: @HassanHAJJAR - What do you think the value of `lbl_mouse.Text` will be after it has finished looping through all of your picture boxes?

Comment: @HassanHAJJAR - And whatever could `object sender` possibly be?

Comment: Replace `lbl_mouse.Text =` with `lbl_mouse.Text +=`

Comment: Also, check the code because you're defining some properties twice and adding twice the `PictureBox` control to the Form's control collection: `Controls.Add(pbox);` and  `this.Controls.Add(pbox);`. It will be added only once, but maybe you wanted to add the newly created `PictureBox` to the collection of your `pb_test` *container*. Then, follow  @jmcilhinney advice and keep a reference of the control that's been dragged. You could subscribe it's `MouseDown` event and update a variable there. Or create a class object that can hold this and other variables you might need to refer to.

Comment: I'm trying your solutions but nothing is working with me!

Comment: @Enigmativity after this loop it will contain the last one, that's why it works on the last one. I removed the foreach loop and created a variable of type int that will be used in the timer to refer to the dragged picture box, but the problem is how to get data of the clicked picture box to shows its (x,y)? I tried to search something like on click but nothing works

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm trying to update the variable that I've created, the problem is how to get the index of the clicked one!

Comment: @HassanHAJJAR - And whatever could `object sender` possibly be? (THIS IS A BIG HINT FOR YOU)